# Convert Rcpp Numeric Vector into boost:ublas:vector

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I'm trying to convert from an `rtype` object to `ublas` from `boost`.

Using some code I found from the [Rcpp dev list regarding ublas](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2011-June/002402.html), I'm able to return the `ublas` vector wrapped as an `rtype`.

e.g.

```
// Converts from ublas to rtype

template <typename T>   
Rcpp::Vector< Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype >
ublas2rcpp( const boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T>& x ){
  return Rcpp::Vector< Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype >(
      x.begin(), x.end()
  ) ;
}
```

To mimick the behavior import behavior, I currently use a loop over `ublas`  vector of the corresponding length and just assign everything from the `rtype` to it.

Would switching from a loop improve performance?

```
// My attempt to convert from rtype to ublas

// so R can find the libraries
//[[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
//[[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

#include <Rcpp.h>


#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

typedef boost::numeric::ublas::vector< double > vector_type;
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix< double > matrix_type;

template <typename T>    /// this need to be fixed up, hopefully working for now though
Rcpp::Vector< Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype >
ublas2rcpp( const boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T>& x ){
  return Rcpp::Vector< Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype >(
      x.begin(), x.end()
  ) ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector main(NumericVector x1)
{


  int L =x1.length();


  vector_type x(L , 0 ); // initialize the vector to all zero

  for(int i=0;i<L;i++)
  {

    x(i) =  x1(i);

  }


return(ublas2rcpp(x));   

}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, I'll try to answer this sometime on Thursday if no one beats me to it.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, sorry for the delay. Hopefully, what I've done makes up for it.

With that being said, let's do this!

## Introduction

The issue is two fold that is being attempted:

1. Converting from R to C++ (`Rcpp::as<T>(obj)`)
2. Converting from C++ to R (`Rcpp::wrap(obj)`)

Luckily, there is a wonderful Rcpp vignette called [Extending Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf) that addresses custom objects. Sadly, the clarity of the vignette leaves a lot to be desired when compared to the other documentation. (I may try to do a PR that improves it.)

So, I'm going to try to take you through the steps with a bit of commentary. Please note that the approach used is via **Templates and partial specialization** and will result in some nice automagic at the end.

## Explanation of

### Stage 1 - Forward Declarations

In the first stage, we must declare our intent to the features we wish to use prior to engaging `Rcpp.h`. To do so, we will load a different header file and add some definitions to the `Rcpp::traits` namespace.

Principally, when we start writing the file, the first header that we must load is `RcppCommon.h` and **not** the usual `Rcpp.h`!! If we do not place the forward declaration prior to the `Rcpp.h` call, we will be unable to appropriately register our extension.

Then, we must provide add in the different plugin markup for `sourceCpp()` to set the appropriate flags during the compilation of the code. After the plugins, we will include the actual boost headers that we want to use. Lastly, we must add two special Rcpp function declaration, `Rcpp::as<T>(obj)` and `Rcpp::wrap(obj)`, within `Rcpp::traits` namespace. To enable multiple types, we must create an `Exporter` class instead of a more direct call to `template <> ClassName as( SEXP )`.

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>

// Flags for C++ compiler

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// Third party library includes that provide the template class of ublas
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

// Provide Forward Declarations
namespace Rcpp {

   namespace traits{

   // Setup non-intrusive extension via template specialization for
   // 'ublas' class boost::numeric::ublas

   // Support for wrap
   template <typename T> SEXP wrap(const boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> & obj);

   // Support for as<T>
   template <typename T> class Exporter< boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> >;

  }
}
```

### Stage 2 - Include the `Rcpp.h`

It might seem frivolous to have a stage just to declare import order, but if `Rcpp.h` is included before the forward declaration then `Rcpp::traits` is not updated and we enter the abyss.

Thus:

```
// >> Place <Rcpp.h> AFTER the forward declaration!!!! <<

#include <Rcpp.h>


// >> Place Definitions of Forward Declarations AFTER <Rcpp.h>!!!! <<
```

### Stage 3 - Implementing the Extensions

Now, we must actually implement the forward declarations. In particular, the only implementation that will be slightly problematic is the `as<>` since the `wrap()` is straight forward.

#### `wrap()`

To implement `wrap()` we must appeal to a built in type conversion index within Rcpp called [`Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/traits/r_sexptype_traits.h). From this, we are able to obtain an `int` containing the `RTYPE` and then construct an `Rcpp::Vector`. For the construction of a matrix, the same ideas hold true.

#### `as()`

For `as<>()`, we need to consider the template that will be passed in. Furthermore, we setup a `typedef` directly underneath the `Exporter` class definition to easily define an `OUT` object to be used within the `get()` method. Outside of that, we use the same trick to move back and forth from a C++ `T` type to an `R` type.

In order to accomplish the `as<>`, or the direct port from R to C++, I had to do something dirty: *I copied the vector contents*. The code that governs this output is given within the `get()` of the `Exporter` class. You may wish to spend some time looking into changing the assignment using pointers perhaps. I'm not very well versed with `ublas` so I did not see an easy approach to resolve the pointer pass.

```
// Define template specializations for as<> and wrap

namespace Rcpp {

namespace traits{

// Defined wrap case
template <typename T> SEXP wrap(const boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> & obj){
  const int RTYPE = Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype ;

  return Rcpp::Vector< RTYPE >(obj.begin(), obj.end());
};


// Defined as< > case
template<typename T>
class Exporter< boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> > {
  typedef typename boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> OUT ;

  // Convert the type to a valid rtype. 
  const static int RTYPE = Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits< T >::rtype ;
  Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> vec;

public:
  Exporter(SEXP x) : vec(x) {
    if (TYPEOF(x) != RTYPE)
      throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong R type for mapped 1D array");
  }
  OUT get() {

    // Need to figure out a way to perhaps do a pointer pass?
    OUT x(vec.size());

    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x.begin()); // have to copy data

    return x;
  }
} ;


}
}
```

### Stage 4 - Testing

Okay, let's see if what we worked on paid off (**spoiler** It did! **spoiler**). To check, we should look at two different areas:

1. Trace diagnostics within the function and;
2. An automagic test.

Both of which are given below. Note that I've opted to shorten the `ublas` setup to just be:

```
// Here we define a shortcut to the boost ublas class to enable multiple ublas types via a template.
// ublas::vector<T> => ublas::vector<double>, ... , ublas::vector<int>
namespace ublas = ::boost::numeric::ublas;
```

#### Trace Diagnostics

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void containment_test(Rcpp::NumericVector x1) {

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Converting from Rcpp::NumericVector to ublas::vector<double>" << std::endl;

  ublas::vector<double> x = Rcpp::as< ublas::vector<double> >(x1); // initialize the vector to all zero

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Running output test with ublas::vector<double>" << std::endl;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < x.size (); ++ i)
    Rcpp::Rcout  << x(i) << std::endl;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Converting from ublas::vector<double> to Rcpp::NumericVector" << std::endl;

  Rcpp::NumericVector test = Rcpp::wrap(x);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Running output test with Rcpp::NumericVector" << std::endl;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < test.size (); ++ i)
    Rcpp::Rcout  << test(i) << std::endl;

}
```

Test Call:

```
containment_test(c(1,2,3,4))
```

Results:

```
Converting from Rcpp::NumericVector to ublas::vector<double>
Running output test with ublas::vector<double>
1
2
3
4
Converting from ublas::vector<double> to Rcpp::NumericVector
Running output test with Rcpp::NumericVector
1
2
3
4
```

This test performed as expected. Onto the next test!

#### Automagic test

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
ublas::vector<double> automagic_ublas_rcpp(ublas::vector<double> x1) {
  return x1;
}
```

Test Call:

```
automagic_ublas_rcpp(c(1,2,3.2,1.2))
```

Results:

```
[1] 1.0 2.0 3.2 1.2
```

Success!

### Stage 5 - All together for the <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Here is the combination of the above code chunks given by stage. If you copy and paste this into your `.cpp` file, then everything *should* work. If not, let me know.

```
// -------------- Stage 1: Forward Declarations with `RcppCommon.h`

#include <RcppCommon.h>

// Flags for C++ compiler
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// Third party library includes that provide the template class of ublas
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>


// Here we use ublas_vec to enable multiple ublas types via a template.
// ublas::vector<T> => ublas::vector<double>, ... , ublas::vector<int>
namespace ublas = ::boost::numeric::ublas;


// Provide Forward Declarations
namespace Rcpp {

  namespace traits{

    // Setup non-intrusive extension via template specialization for
    // 'ublas' class boost::numeric::ublas

    // Support for wrap
    template <typename T> SEXP wrap(const boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> & obj);

    // Support for as<T>
    template <typename T> class Exporter< boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> >;

  }
}

// -------------- Stage 2: Including Rcpp.h

// >> Place <Rcpp.h> AFTER the forward declaration!!!! <<

#include <Rcpp.h>


// >> Place Definitions of Forward Declarations AFTER <Rcpp.h>!!!! <<


// -------------- Stage 3: Implementation of Declarations

// Define template specializations for as<> and wrap

namespace Rcpp {

  namespace traits{

    // Defined wrap case
    template <typename T> SEXP wrap(const boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> & obj){
      const int RTYPE = Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype ;

      return Rcpp::Vector< RTYPE >(obj.begin(), obj.end());
    };


    // Defined as< > case
    template<typename T>
    class Exporter< boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> > {
      typedef typename boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> OUT ;

      // Convert the type to a valid rtype. 
      const static int RTYPE = ::Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits< T >::rtype ;
      Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> vec;

    public:
      Exporter(SEXP x) : vec(x) {
        if (TYPEOF(x) != RTYPE)
          throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong R type for mapped 1D array");
      }
      OUT get() {

        // Need to figure out a way to perhaps do a pointer pass?
        OUT x(vec.size());

        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x.begin()); // have to copy data

        return x;
      }
    } ;


  }
}

// -------------- Stage 4: Tests

// [[Rcpp::export]]
ublas::vector<double> automagic_ublas_rcpp(ublas::vector<double> x1) {
  return x1;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void containment_test(Rcpp::NumericVector x1) {

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Converting from Rcpp::NumericVector to ublas::vector<double>" << std::endl;

  ublas::vector<double> x = Rcpp::as< ublas::vector<double> >(x1); // initialize the vector to all zero

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Running output test with ublas::vector<double>" << std::endl;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < x.size (); ++ i)
    Rcpp::Rcout  << x(i) << std::endl;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Converting from ublas::vector<double> to Rcpp::NumericVector" << std::endl;

  Rcpp::NumericVector test = Rcpp::wrap(x);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Running output test with Rcpp::NumericVector" << std::endl;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < test.size (); ++ i)
    Rcpp::Rcout  << test(i) << std::endl;

}
```

## Closing Remarks

Whew... That was a lot. Hopefully, the above provided enough justification as I believe you may want to extend past a `1D` vector to perhaps a `ublas::matrix` and so on. In addition, the wait should hopefully have been worth it as you now have the autoconvert magic of `Rcpp` so there is no need to call `ublas2rcpp()` within the `return()` statement. In fact, you could simplify specify the return type of the function as `ublas::vector<double>`!

In other news, I think what probably stopped you from being able to create the alternate template function above (e.g. `rcpp2ublas`) was not being able to deduce what C++ `T` type the `Rcpp::Vector` was. Personally, after digging around in the [Rcpp GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rcppcore/rcpp), I'm not sure such a conversion index exists or if it does should be used due to the `Shield` usage. Digging deeper into conversions is an adventure for another day.

Comment: Another Rcpp Gallery post?  It is indeed an (apparently needed) additional tutorial on custom `as<>()` and `wrap()`.

Comment: Sure! Out of pure curiosity there is no mapping from Rtype to Cpp type?

Comment: You mean automagically?  No, the `std::vector<T>` do not appear out of think air but somewhat explicitly, so I guess it needs to be the same for the `ublas::vector<T>`.

Comment: @steve3051980 you can also view the post on http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/

Comment: Coatless thank you so much. I've been trying to figure out how to do thing type thing for quite awhile. It runs fine I'm dissecting your code and comments. This helps a lot!